# How can I solve the react leaflet redirecting?

Tags: reactjs, flutter, react-leaflet

I'm having some troubles with redirecting the map to the bound that I defined.
The problem is that in the web native is working perfectly. But, I'm making a app using flutter and in each button on the app is calling the web page in react.
The issue here is the map. When I press the button on the app, the page is redirectly to my page, and all the information is being loaded, including the points that I want in the map. However, the map isn't centering in the bound that I wanted... And this only happend when I test on the app.

Any guess?

I'm leaving the code bellow:

1. This is the map component that I'm using

```
const [routeSuggested, setRouteSuggested] = useState([])
    const [routeRealized, setRouteRealized] = useState([])
    const [vehicleTruck, setVehicleTruck] = useState(null);
    const [vehicleAggregate, setVehicleAggregate] = useState(null);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState([-23.673571, -46.576755])
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(14)
    const [bounds, setBounds] = useState([])
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)

    const getCoordsRoute = () => {
        var coordsVehicle = [vehicleMonitored?.lastLat, vehicleMonitored?.lastLng]

        var coordsNotCompleted = tasks
            .filter((task) => task.completed === false)
            .map((task) => [task.lat, task.lng])

        return [coordsVehicle, ...coordsNotCompleted]
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestData = async () => {
            let routeDone = []
            let routeSuggest = []
            let listCoord = getCoordsRoute()

            if (scheduleDetail?.scheduleStatusId !== 8 && listCoord.length > 1) {
                var responseRoutes = await getRequestPathRouteOSRM(listCoord)
                var routeOSRM = responseRoutes?.data.routes[0]

                if (routeOSRM) {
                    routeSuggest = routeOSRM.geometry.coordinates.map(item => [
                        item[1], item[0]
                    ])
                    setRouteSuggested(routeSuggest)
                }

                setVehicleTruck(scheduleDetail.vehicle)
                setVehicleAggregate(scheduleDetail.vehicleAggregate)
            }
            else {
                setRouteSuggested([])
                setVehicleTruck(null)
                setVehicleAggregate(null)
            }

            if (scheduleDetail) {
                let schedId = scheduleDetail.scheduleId
                var responseTrips = await getLocationVehicleTrips(token, schedId)
            }

            if (responseTrips) {
                routeDone = responseTrips.map(item => [item.lat, item.long])
                setRouteRealized(routeDone)
            }

            let boundsCenter = [...routeDone, ...routeSuggest]
            if (boundsCenter.length === 0) {
                boundsCenter = tasks.map(item => [item.lat, item.lng])
            }

            setBounds(boundsCenter)
            setIsLoaded(true)
        }
        requestData()

    }, [scheduleDetail])

    const handleMarkerIcon = (index) => {
        return (
            new L.divIcon({
                html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <div
                        style={{
                            width: "30px",
                            height: "30px",
                            border: "1px solid #FFF",
                            borderRadius: "50%",
                            background: tasks[index].statusTask.color,
                            color: "#FFF",
                            position: "absolute",
                            left: "-13px",
                            bottom: "-16px"
                        }}
                    >
                        <strong style={{
                            display: "flex",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            height: "100%"
                        }}>{handleItemLetter(index)}</strong>
                    </div>
                ),
                iconAnchor: [12, 0],
            })
        )
    }

    const zoomActual = (getZoom) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setZoom(getZoom)
        }, 1000);
    }

return (
        <>
            <MapContainer center={position} style={{ height: "40vh" }} zoom={13} >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Polyline color="#0000FF" weight={6} opacity="0.8" positions={routeRealized} />
                <Polyline color="#753eb3" weight={6} opacity="0.8" positions={routeSuggested} />
                {isLoaded ? <LocationMarker bounds={bounds} zoom={zoomActual} /> : null}

                {tasks.length > 0 && tasks.map((point, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Marker key={index} position={[point.lat, point.lng]} icon={handleMarkerIcon(index)} />
                    )
                })}
                <VehicleAggregatePosition vehicleAggregate={vehicleAggregate} />
                <VehicleTruckPosition vehicleTruck={vehicleTruck} />
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    )
```

2. Inside the Map Component, I'm using another component called **LocationMarker**:

````
    useEffect(() => {
        const getLocation = async () => {
            map.locate()
        }

        getLocation()
    }, [bounds])

    const map = useMapEvents({
        locationfound() {
            map.fitBounds(bounds)
        },
        zoom() {
            zoom(map.getZoom())
        }
    })

}```

Is important to be told that the app is made by other person, so I don't have any controll about that
````

Comment: It could be that the map is being loaded before the bounds are set in the app. In a web browser, the map component may have enough time to load and center on the bounds before the map is displayed to the user. 

When you go to mobile, the component may not have enough time to load before the map is displayed, resulting in the map centering on a default position.

Try to wrap the MapContainer component in a conditional statement that checks if the bounds have been set and only renders the MapContainer if the bounds exist.

Comment: @RenêCardozo I already resolved this problem. The problem was the aplication on mobile wasn't understanding the line "map.locate()". So, I put the map.fitBounds directly there and it worked. But I think your suggestion was a great one, but in this case I would have to change all the UX/UI. Anyway, thanks and vai Brasil hahaha